# Reducing runtime of method from 24 hours to 1 hour

Tags: c#, performance, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

I have a 'For' loop I need to run from 0 to 2,147,483,647 (int.MaxValue). Inside the loop I'm calling a method that calculates a very complex equation and it returns the value for each parameter. I wish to get the highest return value.

The total runtime of my for loop takes about full 24 hours. How and can I reduce the runtime of my code to only one hour? Maybe 4 hours if I will use distributed computing?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CheckValuesZeroToMaxInt();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void CheckValuesZeroToMaxInt()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            ComplexMath(i);
        }
    }
```

I know how to use 'Parallel.For', but still this offers very little help. How can I take my c# code and run it on a cluster of computers to get the return value from my method in no time? Is there a site that offers this service for a low or free cost?

Comment: Well how many cores do you have access to? Is the problem genuinely embarrassingly parallelizable (as it appears)? It would be *simpler* to do this on one machine with several cores, but you could distribute it if necessary.

Comment: If the calls are independent of one another, why not just use `Parallel.For()`?

Comment: Without knowing what `ComplexMath` is doing, I don't see how we could possibly give a complete answer.  An empty loop (without the function call) takes at most a few seconds.

Comment: Make `ComplexMath` run faster. It's a flip answer, but consider the question: Here's some code that takes .00001% of the execution time. I also have a function that takes 99.99999% of the time which I'm not showing. How do I make it 24 times faster? Well you could run it on a 30+ core computer and parallelize it, or run it on 30 different computers each doing a portion of the range. Or, you could optimize your function that takes all the time, and possibly speed it up by 100 or 1000 times.

Comment: Can you please show me how to run this code on 10 or more computers? Is there a site that give this service for free?

Comment: As @hatchet said, make `ComplexMath` run faster, regardless of whether you exploit parallelism, because the speedup multiple you get will apply regardless of whatever else you do. [*This is the method I and many others use*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771), to look for speedup opportunities. If your `ComplexMath` has any simple ways to be made faster, it will find them.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do it on one machine would be with the [Parallel.For-loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783539%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
private static void CheckValuesZeroToMaxInt()
{
    object maxValueLock = new object();
    int maxValue = int.MinValue;

    Parallel.For(0, int.MaxValue, i =>
    {
        int tmpMaxValue = ComplexMath(i);

        if (tmpMaxValue > maxValue)
        {
            lock(maxValueLock)
            {
                if (tmpMaxValue > maxValue)
                    maxValue = tmpMaxValue;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(maxValue);
}
```

However, since your `ComplexMath` function only takes ~0.04ms ([(24 / (2^31)) * 3600 * 1000](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2824+%2F+%282%5E31%29%29+%2a+3600+%2a+1000)) to execute, you'd maybe get stuck with the constant locking and wouldn't get almost any improvement. To prevent this from happening, we can change the above function to execute more steps within a thread.

```
const long million = 1000*1000;

private static void CheckValuesZeroToMaxInt()
{
    object maxValueLock = new object();
    int maxValue = int.MinValue;

    Parallel.For(0, (int.MaxValue / million) + 1, i =>
    {
        int privateMaxValue = int.MinValue;

        for (long j = i * million; j < (i+1) * million && j < int.MaxValue; j++)
        {
            int tmpMaxValue = ComplexMath(j);

            if (tmpMaxValue > privateMaxValue)
            {
                privateMaxValue = tmpMaxValue;
            }
        }

        lock(maxValueLock)
        {
            if (privateMaxValue > maxValue)
                maxValue = privateMaxValue;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(maxValue);
}
```

The second version should scale pretty much linearly with the number of processors, so if you run it on a machine with 24 cores, it will finish within 1h. Of course instead of Parallel.For you can use any kind of communication to distribute the computation between multiple machines.